# Where to find English translations of Euler's collected works?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, math-history

I will highly appreciate if someone can provide me the link to the book or link to the paper where I can find the following papers $(90-94)$ with English translation.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe useful [The Euler Archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/)

Comment: Yeah..thanks..but I want english translation

Comment: There are 204 documents translated.

Comment: Perhaps this is more helpful: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See the question..now..I have edited

Comment: The first one is the number 41.

Comment: I recently spent several hours poking around the Euler archive, and I did not find it's organization helpful. I would very much like to get a list of the (famously lucid" textbooks of Euler that exist in English translation. They may all be on the Euler archive, but I found no unified list of english translations and no lit at all of his textbooks, and I did notdo much better in several library databases. But I found and bought the three books from the Euler  tricentenial, and am looking forward to rerading them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Euler Archive](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/) provides links with english translations:

$\textbf{90}:$ [E41 -- De summis serierum reciprocarum](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E041.html) [[english translation](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0506415)]

$\textbf{91}:$ [E47 -- Inventio summae cuiusque seriei ex dato termino generali](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E047.html) [[english translation](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4096)]

$\textbf{92}:$ [E72 -- Variae observationes circa series infinitas](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E072.html)  [ [english translation](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4096)]

$\textbf{93}:$ [E596 -- De summa seriei ex numeris primis formatae](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E596.html) [ [english translation](http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2564)]

$\textbf{94}:$ [E792 -- Tractatus de numerorum doctrina](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E792.html) [[english translation](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/docs/translations/E792en.pdf)]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts.